# Distinct query with sum operator not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question, I have this query where I'm supposed to pull the totals group by PIX_SKU. My issue here is that is doubling the quantities, any help will be appreciate it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A2.PIX_SKU), A2.PIX_DATE, SUM(A1.ID_QTY) AS TOTAL
FROM IDCASE00_EXTRACT A1,PX_CLEAN A2
WHERE A1.ID_SKU = A2.PIX_SKU
GROUP BY A2.PIX_SKU, A2.PIX_DATE
```

Here is some data for table IDCASE00_EXTRACT

```
   id_sku                  id_ty       
301110  39  8               3266         
301110  39  8               1788         
301112  90  1               4           
301185  20  6               6580        
301185  20  6               22028
```

Here is some data for table PX_CLEAN

```
  pix_sku           pix_date
301110  39  8       20120203
301112  90  1       20120204
301185  20  6       20120320
301110  39  8       20120301
301185  20  6       20120209
```

Comment: Can you post the two tables with some sample data separately?

Comment: I can see the following issues with your question: 1. Your example of data shows only one table, but the query references two. 2. You've tagged your question as related to two different database systems, MySQL and SQL Server. Was that on purpose or you just mistook `mysql` for `mssql`? 3. You are using `DISTINCT` as if it can be applied to a column, which it can't. `DISTINCT` always applies to the entire row of columns you are pulling.

Comment: Venk, I posted the two tables.

Comment: Andriy, 1. I posted the two tables now. 2. I accidentally tag MySql. 3. How can I do that?

Comment: Re: "How can I do that?" – If you want distinct PIX_SKUs in the output, you should *not* include PIX_DATE in GROUP BY. If you want some PIX_DATE values in your output and, at the same time, insist on having distinct PIX_SKUs, you should probably pull PIX_DATEs with aggregating, like `MAX(PIX_DATE)` or `MIN(PIX_DATE)`. Pay also attention to both answers.

Answer (score 5):

Your join is the problem ...

In `IDCASE00_EXTRACT`, you have two rows where `id_sku = 301110 39 8`.

In `PX_CLEAN`, you also have two rows where `pix_sku = 301110 39 8`.

So when you join on `id_sku = pix_sku` you're generating 4 rows (2 * 2).

So the match that joins the two tables is not currently unique - is there a date in `IDCASE00_EXTRACT` that should match the `pix_date` in `PX_CLEAN`?

Answer (score 2):

This query should get you the total for each SKU:

```
SELECT Q.ID_SKU, SUM(Q.ID_qty) AS TOTAL
FROM   IDCASE00_EXTRACT AS Q
GROUP BY Q.ID_SKU
```

What do you intend to do with the pix_date? What use does this data have?

The only other information which you can get that I can think of is:

```
SELECT T.ID_SKU, T.TOTAL, PX.pix_date
FROM
     (  
     SELECT Q.ID_SKU, SUM(Q.ID_qty) AS TOTAL
     FROM   IDCASE00_EXTRACT AS Q
     GROUP BY Q.ID_SKU
     ) 
     AS T JOIN PX_CLEAN AS PX ON (T.ID_SKU = PX.pix_sku)
```

Anyway, you have to clarify what information you want to retrieve.

Comment: I need to get a distinct result for PIX_SKU, I need to show the PIX_SKU, PIX_DATE and SUM(ID_QTY). Hope this clarifies what I need!!

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT pix_sku, SUM(id_qty) AS QuantityTotal
FROM @PX_CLEAN AS P
    JOIN @IDCASE00_EXTRACT AS Q ON (Q.id_sku = P.pix_sku)
GROUP BY pix_sku
```

will get those results:

- *SKU*           |    *TOTAL*
- 301110  39  8 |    10108
- 301112  90  1 |    4
- 301185  20  6 |   57216

For each SKU, u have a total.

What exactly do you want to get from the pix_date? You have only **ONE** sku when you aggregate, but there are still several dates for each single SKU. What are u trying to get? what do you want to know?

You should stop thinking about the DISTINCT function. This function only removes the exactly same **rows** from the query results. It helps only if u got the results that u want - but there are multiple lines which are the same. The query engine wont "understand" your wishes and just return 1 row for each SKU with distinct, that can be achieved only by aggregation (group by).